# PHP get Google spreadsheet data with authentication (additional: send row data to google doc)

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api, google-oauth

I'm currently developing a php page that will get spreadsheet data and display it in a datatable. I have done so by publishing my spreadsheet and getting the JSON object through spreadsheet url/key.

I have been successful in doing so :

[image: From public google spreadsheet]

Now, I have been requested an enhancement, I need to change the functionality of the 'print  pdf' button to actually get the row data and create and populate a google doc. I'm thinking that I would need authentication for that and the implementation of accessing the google spreadsheet would change. Could anyone give me a nice example cause I am fairly new with google api and php in general.

I tried to read samples from developer.google but I'm having trouble understanding them.

Thanks a lot!